# convergence of integral function sequence

Tags: measure-theory

Given the function sequence $f_n(x)  = \frac{1}{(1 + \frac{x}{n})^n (x)^{\frac{1}{n}}} $ we are asked to investigate the convergence of:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{x \in [0,\infty]} f_n(x) dx$$

I know the sequence $f_n$ is not pointwise convergent.  I'm unclear if we should try to use Beppo-Levi as I don't believe using Dominated Convergence Theory applies since the sequence is not pointwise convergent.

Comment: I didn't make that edit it was someone else who incorrectly changed the denominator, it's been corrected

Comment: The sequence is certainly pointwise convergent. The limit is $e^{-x}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $n^{1/n} \to 1$ it is enough to find the limit of $\int_0^{\infty} \frac 1 {(1+x/n)^{n} (x/n)^{1/n}} dx$. Put $t=\frac x  n$ to get $\int_0^{\infty}\frac 1 {(1+t)^{n} t^{1/n}}dt$. Split the integral into $\int_0^{1}$ and $\int_1^{\infty}$. In the first part the integrand tends to $0$ and it is dominated by the integrable function $t^{-1/2}$ for $n \geq 2$. In the second part the integrand tends to $0$ and it is dominated by the integrable function $\frac 1  {(1+t)^{2}}$ for $n \geq 2$. Hence, the required limit is $0$.

Comment: mistyped the function sequence

Comment: @mathcompguy It is not a mistype. He divided $x$ by $n$ on purpose (he says "since $n^{1/n}\rightarrow 1$" which explains why this is possible)

Comment: you cannot apply DCT since fn is not pointwise convergent and thus the limit does not commute.

Comment: $f_n (x) \to \frac 1{ e^{x}}$ for every $x \in (0,\infty)$.  @mathcompguy